# Unity C# Class new method gives an error 'Class' doesn't contain a definition for 'name'

Tags: unity-game-engine

so I have 2 scripts and I'm trying to use inheritance from one to the other.
first class is empty (I'm trying to learn how to use inheritances),
the other has this code

```
public class InheritanceTest : MonoBehaviour

   Dragon.dragon = new Dragon();
```

I'm getting an error that says: `'Dragon' doesn't contain a definition for 'dragon'`

Answer (score 0):

To make an instance of a class you can do this Dragon dragon = new Dragon();